# How were the Weasley twins punished for throwing snowballs at the back of Prof. Quirrell's turban?

Tags: harry-potter

I read this line which comes from *[Harry Potter and the Philosopher’s Stone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter_and_the_Philosopher%27s_Stone)*.

> The Weasley twins were punished for bewitching several snowballs, so that they followed Quirrell around, bouncing off the back of his turban.

We later learn the back of Prof. Quirrell's turban hides

> the face of Lord Voldemort. Which means the Weasley twins' enchanted snowballs pummeled Voldemort in the face several times.

**So how were the Weasley twins punished by Hogwarts staff?**

I can believe the recipient of that prank would want to inflict his own form of punishment on the twins.

Please provide quotes from the book to support your answer instead of just posting speculative replies.

Comment: Think about that for a second. Voldemort got hit in the face.

Answer (score 1):

Prof Quirrell was a very cowardly wizard. So even though the twins had no intention of exposing his secret of keeping Voldemort on the back of his head, Quirrell must not have given them any heavy punishment in order to not fetch any unwanted attention.

Comment: It's not that the twins had no **intention** of exposing Quirrell's secret. They had no **knowledge** of this secret.

Comment: that's what i was trying to say. they had no knowledge, they were just trying to tease him.